# Criteria with full join and left join

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hql, criteria

I am trying to write a query using the criteria class

```
select *
from A full join B on
A.aid=B.aid
left join C on
C.bid=B.bid
```

So far I have

```
criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class, "A")
                    .createCriteria("B", "B").createCriteria("C", "C")
```

which is a join on a inner join I do not want that

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class, "A", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
                .createCriteria("B", "B").createCriteria("C", "C", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```